# Compact way that searches multiple alists

Tags: alists

I have a collection of alists, `ptc-1` through `ptc-5`.  Would it be possible
to make the following code more compact, rather having to add more sections
if there are more alists?

```
(let ( (v "") )

  (setq v (cdr (assoc word ptc-1)))
  (unless (null v)
     (add-to-list 'ptc
         (replace-regexp-in-string word v word)))

  (setq v (cdr (assoc word alist-2)))
  (unless (null v)
     (add-to-list 'ptc
         (replace-regexp-in-string word v word)))
  
  (setq v (cdr (assoc word alist-3)))
  (unless (null v)
     (add-to-list 'ptc
         (replace-regexp-in-string word v word)))

  (setq v (cdr (assoc word alist-4)))
  (unless (null v)
     (add-to-list 'ptc
         (replace-regexp-in-string word v word)))

  (setq v (cdr (assoc word alist-5)))
  (unless (null v)
     (add-to-list 'ptc
         (replace-regexp-in-string word v word))) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to loop over each of the alists with a `dolist` loop macro. So something like:

```
(let ((v ""))
  (dolist (alist (list ptc-1 ptc-2 ptc-3 ptc-4 ptc-5))
    (setq v (cdr (assoc word alist)))
    (unless (null v)
       (add-to-list 'ptc
           (replace-regexp-in-string word v word)))
  v)
```

For a shorter example, `(dolist (x '(64 65 66)) (insert x))` would insert `ABC` into the current buffer.

I also took the liberty of assuming the list of alists contained `ptc-1` through `ptc-5`, unlike your example above which used `alist-2` through `alist-5`.

However, just as a suggestion, if you are iterating over multiple alists like this, it might help to think of one data structure that you could operate on instead of 5 different parallel structures. I don't have a sense of the problem space here so I can't make any suggestions, but might be something worth considering.

Comment: Because of the possibility of having many lists, I would prefer to construct the `alist` name by having `ptc-N`, then calling each one, without having to make a big collection such as your `alist`.

Comment: In the example above `alist` is a variable name representing each of the alists you mentioned. We could also format this as `(defvar alists-to-iterate (list ptc-1 ptc-2 ...)) (dolist (alist alists-to-iterate) ...)`. So if you have more lists to iterate you would add them to `alists-to-iterate`. Otherwise, perhaps I'm not understanding your intention here. I thought you wanted to avoid adding additional blocks for each alist that you needed to iterate. Could you clarify your intent a little?

Comment: Just a variable then.  Thought that `alist (list ...` would make one massive `alist` with all the contents of the lists in it.

Comment: Suppose the list names are painfully long. such as  `andromeda-dictionary-word-assoc-list-N` etc,  and I have 90 of them (`N=90`).  Can I avoid having to list them one by one?

Comment: Was thinking to construct the `alist` symbols with `mapcar`.